# Apache Spark - Selecting some fields unmodified from a Row in Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts: string, name: string, value: string ]
```

and I am trying to do

```
val result = df.map {case Row(ts, name, value) => (name+":"+value+"-ctag", ts)}
```

Essentially 2nd field in the result is unmodified. However I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.javaClass(JavaMirrors.scala:555)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToJava$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:1211)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToJava$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:1203)
  at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toJava$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:49)
```

If I don't select the 2nd field as is, but apply some transformation like below

```
val result = df.map {case Row(ts, name, value) => (name+":"+value+"-ctag", ts+"test")}
```

it works without any issue.

Can you please explain what this error is saying ? I would like to apply transformation on some fields and not on some other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do pattern-matching on `Row`, all your variables are of type `Any`. If you concatenate an `Any` with a `String`, then the result is an `String` (this is the case in your second example).

Try this instead:

```
val result = df.map {case Row(ts:String, name:String, value:String) => (name+":"+value+"-ctag", ts)}
```